# How to render an epub file in React-Native in 2022

Tags: react-native, epub

I would like to know how to render an ebook in my react-native app. All epub readers are no longer working. They are deprecated, like this one: https://github.com/futurepress/epubjs-rn and duofolio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will not work. As its last commit was in 2019 and between 2019 to 2022 react-native has gone through many changes. So, that package is now deprecated. So you have to switch to a new package. You can use the new [React Native ePub Reader](https://github.com/victorsoares96/epubjs-react-native)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the package you mentioned is for React. Does it work in react-native?

Comment: @Raul I've updated the link you can check now :)

Comment: Thanks a lot again. But this is a PDF reader, not an epub reader.

Comment: Ok, so you want an epub reader. I thought you needed a pdf reader. But no problem I've added this time a new pdf reader that is a react native ePub reader :)

Comment: Very good. That one worked. But I'm not being able to render an epub file inside my app, just the opf file of the example. Do you know why? 

Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't say. I don't have your code with me. You can now complete this questing by marking as answer and then create a new question with eh code and share the link with me I'll be glad to help you :)

Comment: same problem here... , only works with the opf file and not EPUB

Comment: Does anyone find a working reader for the epub file? in react native